# TailwindCSS output css file 424 lines

Tags: tailwind-css

I follow the Tailwind documentation about installing Tailwind using CLI but output.css file has only 424 lines whereas it should have thousands.

Comment: Why do you think it should have thousands? Please add some of your code and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this same issue, here is how I fixed it.

When following the docs I was running the command `npx tailwindcss build...`. It turns out I should have been using the command `npx tailwindcss-cli build...`. When running the first command I get an output of 424 lines. When running the second I get an output of several thousand lines.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. Feels like they moved it from `npx tailwindcss build...` to `npx tailwindcss-cli build...` as @Leithen Crider mentioned above.

Fixed it by using this in my build script: `"npx tailwindcss-cli build -i src/style.css -o public/output.css -w"`

Comment: -w is for --watch so whenever i edit my src style.css file, it will rebuild the public output.css file.

Comment: Glad this helped!